# Select a column from dual and populate it with different values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi I am on Oracle and need some help.

I am creating a select statement that generates a and 3 columns and end_date, table_name & kpi using the dual table. I have created the first two columns however for the third column I want to populate it with 4 different kpis for each date and I am not sure how to do this as I can only populate it with one value.

```
SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'iw') - LEVEL AS end_date, 'MyTable' AS table_name , 'kpi_1' as kpi
  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7
```

Your help will be very much appreciated.

This is the output I would like to see

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryz2x.png)

Comment: What is the output you would like to see?

Comment: I would like to see the following output

Comment: Can you describe the tables you are trying to query and get information from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you are looking for something like this:

```
with dates (d) as
(SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'iw') - LEVEL
  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7
),
kpis (kpi) as
(select 'kpi_1' from dual union all 
 select 'kpi_2' from dual union all 
 select 'kpi_3' from dual union all 
 select 'kpi_4' from dual
)
SELECT d, 'MyTable' AS table_name , kpi
  FROM dates 
       CROSS JOIN kpis
```

Result:

```
D        TABLE_NAME KPI
09/03/2017  MyTable kpi_1
09/03/2017  MyTable kpi_2
09/03/2017  MyTable kpi_3
09/03/2017  MyTable kpi_4
09/02/2017  MyTable kpi_1
09/02/2017  MyTable kpi_2
09/02/2017  MyTable kpi_3
09/02/2017  MyTable kpi_4
09/01/2017  MyTable kpi_1
09/01/2017  MyTable kpi_2
09/01/2017  MyTable kpi_3
09/01/2017  MyTable kpi_4
08/31/2017  MyTable kpi_1
08/31/2017  MyTable kpi_2
08/31/2017  MyTable kpi_3
08/31/2017  MyTable kpi_4
08/30/2017  MyTable kpi_1
08/30/2017  MyTable kpi_2
08/30/2017  MyTable kpi_3
08/30/2017  MyTable kpi_4
08/29/2017  MyTable kpi_1
08/29/2017  MyTable kpi_2
08/29/2017  MyTable kpi_3
08/29/2017  MyTable kpi_4
08/28/2017  MyTable kpi_1
08/28/2017  MyTable kpi_2
08/28/2017  MyTable kpi_3
08/28/2017  MyTable kpi_4
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a [case expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) can help:

```
SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'iw') - LEVEL AS end_date, 
             'MyTable' AS table_name , 
             CASE 
                WHEN level <= 2 THEN 'kpi_1' 
                WHEN level <= 4 THEN 'kpi_2'
                WHEN level <= 6 THEN 'kpi_3'
                ELSE 'kpi_4'
             END as KPI
  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7

END_DATE         TABLE_N KPI  
---------------- ------- -----
2017/09/03 00:00 MyTable kpi_1
2017/09/02 00:00 MyTable kpi_1
2017/09/01 00:00 MyTable kpi_2
2017/08/31 00:00 MyTable kpi_2
2017/08/30 00:00 MyTable kpi_3
2017/08/29 00:00 MyTable kpi_3
2017/08/28 00:00 MyTable kpi_4
```